# Creating R package: ERROR: installing package indices failed

Tags: r, installation, devtools, r-package

Surprisingly, I don't see previous SO clearly discussing this issue.

I'm creating an R package. All dependencies are installed. The source code is (as far as I can tell) correctly annotated for roxygen2.

Within the package root, the following commands are successful:

Documenting the package works:

`> devtools::document()`

Building the package works:

`> devtools::build()`

Installing the package fails:

`> devtools::install()`

```
** R
** data
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 18 elements
ERROR: installing package indices failed
```

I'm at a loss at to why. Are there any troubleshooting tips for this?

Comment: what does `devtools::check()` note? Is there a (maybe) github repository that illustrate this issue?

Comment: @Tom `devtools::check()` just records the same error. RE: repo. I will make it public soon. Otherwise, I could somehow PM you

Comment: sure, I updated my SO-profile to show a link to a web presence of mine where you can find my E-Mail adress if you don't mind taking the trouble